# How to convert correlated subquery to join when using CASE WHEN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, netezza

I have a query:

```
CASE WHEN T3.ID_NUMBER IN (20216) THEN 'Retired'
```

I wanted to add a subquery to it:

```
CASE WHEN T3.ID_NUMBER IN (20216) 
AND T1.DEPARTMENT 

NOT IN 

(SELECT T1.DEPARTMENT WHERE
((T.JOB_TYPE IN ('TESTING') AND T2.GROUP IN ('A', 'C', 'D')) OR 
((T.JOB_TYPE IN ('PRODUCTION') AND T2.GROUP IN ('G', 'E')))

THEN 'Retired'
```

As CASE WHEN clause in SQL does not support correlated subquery (here the subquery after not in clause), so how we can convert it to JOIN ?

The subquery I want to convert to join:

```
(SELECT T1.DEPARTMENT WHERE
((T.JOB_TYPE IN ('TESTING') AND T2.GROUP IN ('A', 'C', 'D')) OR 
((T.JOB_TYPE IN ('PRODUCTION') AND T2.GROUP IN ('G', 'E')))
```

Running the above code showing : This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting.

How I can convert this to JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

edited my answer:

try a left join and distinct in the sub-query as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT T1.DEPARTMENT AS DEPARTMENT WHERE
((T.JOB_TYPE IN ('TESTING') AND T2.GROUP IN ('A', 'C', 'D')) OR 
((T.JOB_TYPE IN ('PRODUCTION') AND T2.GROUP IN ('G', 'E'))) TT1 ON T1.DEPARTMENT = TT1.DEPARTMENT
```

and the case in select statement should look like:

```
CASE WHEN T3.ID_NUMBER IN (20216) AND TT1.DEPARTMENT IS NOT NULL THEN 'Retired' ELSE '' END AS Retired
```

Comment: When I add the code to the main code, should I remove the NOT IN clause?

Comment: Yes, i edited my answer. hope it makes more sense now.